# Taylor Series for even orders

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor polynomial of order $2n$ at $0$ of the function

$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Show that the remainder approaches 0 as n increases, if $−1 < x < 1$. Use this to compute $\ln2$ to $2$ decimal places.

I'm confused because the taylor series is defined by only odd powers so I'm confused as to how you would find the even orders. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Our function is $\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$. Use the standard series.  A Taylor polynomial of even order $2n$ will have "last term" $(0)x^{2n}$.

Comment: The function is odd:
$$f(-x)=\ln\frac{1+(-x)}{1-(-x)} = \ln\frac{1-x}{1+x} = - \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} = -f(x)$$
so indeed only odd powers will have a non-zero coefficient. But you are asked to find the Taylor polynomial of (up to) order $2n$, not only the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ (which would be $0$). This means you'll also have to find all odd coefficients up to $2n-1$.

Comment: So when you're finding the Taylor polynomial, I've come up with

Comment: @b-ballboy8:  Your last comment ended prematurely.

Comment: So when you're finding the Taylor polynomial, I've come up with $$2x+\frac 23x^3+\frac 25x^5...$$   How do you denote that you're stopping at the order 2n.

Comment: You would need to give something of the form $$a_1 x+ a_3 x^3 + \dots + a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1} + o(x^{2n})$$ for some explicit coefficients $a_k$'s. Here, for instance you have $a_1=2$, etc.

Comment: Also, what does the original question mean by a remainder?

Comment: Here, I implicitly assumed the remainder was going to zero, as I wrote $o(x^{2n})$. You need to show that $\lvert f(x) - P_{2n}(x)\rvert$ (what I wrote as $o(x^{2n})$) goes to $0$ when $n\to\infty$, for any fixed $x\in(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{1}{1-x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k+\frac{x^n}{1-x}\\
\text{integrating,}\\
\int_0^t \frac{dx}{1-x}
&=\int_0^t\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k dx+\int_0^t\frac{x^n dx}{1-x}\\
\text{or}\\
-\ln(1-t)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^t x^k dx+\int_0^t\frac{x^n dx}{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^t\frac{x^n dx}{1-x}\\
\end{array}
$

Replacing $t$ by $-t$,

$\begin{array}\\
-\ln(1+t)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}t^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^{-t}\frac{x^n dx}{1-x}\\
\text{or}\\
\ln(1+t)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}t^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^{t}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n dx}{1+x}\\
\end{array}
$

These are two series
with the error terms.
Add them to get

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(\frac{1+t}{1-t})
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+(-1)^{k+1})t^{k+1}}{k+1}
+\int_0^{t}x^ndx\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{(1+(-1)^{k+1})t^{k+1}}{k+1}
+\int_0^{t}x^{2n}dx\left(\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
\qquad\text{replacing }n \text{ by }2n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
+\int_0^{t}x^{2n}dx\left(\frac{-1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
\qquad\text{the terms with even } k \text{ are zero}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
+\int_0^{t}x^{2n}dx\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

You can bound
the error terms by using
$t\, \min(f(x))
\le \int_0^t f(x) dx
\le t\, \max(f(x))
$.

As is often the case,
this is not original,
but is a modification
of a proof I saw.

Answer (score 0):

Start with 
$$
\ln \left( \frac{1+x} {1 -x} \right) = \ln \left( 1 + x \right) - \ln \left( 1 - x \right)
$$

Resolve numerator
$$
\ln \left( 1 + x \right) =
x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} - \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \dots - \frac{x^{2n}}{2n} + \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + \dots
$$
and denominator
$$
\ln \left( 1 - x \right) =
-x - \frac{x^{2}}{2}- \frac{x^{3}}{3}- \frac{x^{4}}{4} - \dots - \frac{x^{n}}{n} - \dots
$$
Combine them
$$
\ln \left( \frac{1+x} {1 -x} \right) = 2\left( x + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{5}}{5} + \dots\right)
$$

Numeric computation: 
$$
\frac{1+x} {1 -x} = 2 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = \frac{1}{3}
$$

$$
\ln \left( \frac{1+\frac{1}{3}} {1 -\frac{1}{3}} \right) \approx 
2\left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3} \right) \approx 0.658
$$

Compare to $\ln 2  = 0.693147\dots$